React Quill: how to have text aligned left and right in the same row
Using React Quill text editor, I want to allow the users to create a line of text in which part of the text is aligned to the left, and other is aligned to the right.

DOCS says that the align property is only applied in block: https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/#block
So, using the editor format option, the alignment are applied to the entire line, which turns the behavior that I desire impossible.
Even changing directly the HTML string on the database, f.ex, to:
 <p style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
  <span>
    left
  </span>
  <span>
    right
  </span>
</p>

The editor then displays two rows aligned to the left.
I also tried approaches with the align property, using two paragraphs inside one...
There is some way to achieve it? It looks a thing that should be easy to do. Maybe I'm missing some simple config?
